# Same visible character but different bytes

Tags: vim, text, utf-8, character-encoding, uniq

I have two files each with the same ([Hindi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindi)) word but I copied the word for each file from different sources. While the words from both the sources are alike visually, their bytes are different. The files are [here](http://www.wikiupload.com/MAGPIM65C3DWHKW) and [here](http://www.wikiupload.com/ELHKFUFACH6AP5T). I am not sure about the original encoding in both cases but opening the file as UTF-8 displays the characters correctly.

It is also interesting that when I do unique using the uniq utility only one entry is returned however when I place them in a file and did sort u in vim, I get both the entries.

Please explain what's going on.

Update:

If you do not want to open the links, the Python literals: `'\u091c\u0941\u095c\n'` and `'\u091c\u0941\u0921\u093c\n'` and the word looks like

[image: hindi]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence …?

Comment: And please post a sample here, not on some file-sharing site.

Comment: @deceze Sorry about using file sharing if that's unacceptable. But I check other posts asking about uploading a file and followed that. Have uploaded the files so that anyone can reproduce the issues because an image of the word would be useless. If you can suggest me a better approach, I'd be more than happy to do that.

Comment: As Python literals: `'\u091c\u0941\u095c\n'` and `'\u091c\u0941\u0921\u093c\n'`.

Comment: @JoshLee Thanks Josh. Will update the question.

Comment: @deceze Please post your comment as the answer. The problem indeed is Unicode equivalence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `095C` is `DEVANAGARI LETTER DDDHA`: ड़
- `0921` is `DEVANAGARI LETTER DDA`: ड
- `093C` is `DEVANAGARI SIGN NUKTA` (dot below character): ़

You can see in Python that those are equivalent (Python 3 syntax here):

```
import unicodedata
unicodedata.normalize('NFC', '\u0921\u093c') == unicodedata.normalize('NFC', '\u095c')
# => True
```

You should be able to use `:%!uconv -x any-nfc` (with ICU installed), or `:%!ruby -ne 'puts $_.unicode_normalize(:nfc)'` (with Ruby installed) to normalise your file.

Answer (score 2):

Vim says:

> `:h :sort`
>   The details about sorting depend on the library function used.  There is no
>   guarantee that sorting obeys the current locale.  You will have to try it out.

Meanwhile `uniq` (and I suppose gnu coreutils `sort`, not the vim command) are unicode aware and know how to collate text.

Press <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> or <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>8</kbd> on a character in vim to see the code points or bytes, respectively, that make up a single character.